# "selectize-dropdown-content" empty after dynamically creating new div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, selectize.js, cocoon-gem

I'm using Rails, JQuery, Cocoon, and Selectize to create a form on a page. The application is used to create a menu for a restaurant.

`/menu/new` gives you a page where you can enter the menu name (e.g. "Lunch") as well as a button that says "add menu items", and a "create menu" button. The idea is that when you click to add a menu item, a form appears with fields for Category, Item name, Price, and Description. You can add as many menu items as you want.

My issue isn't one of functionality because everything works fine. The create action will create the Menu, Menu Items, and Menu Item Categories as desired. My issue is with Selectize.

Clicking "add new menu item" gives you the form for a menu item as I mentioned earlier, and in that form "Category" is a drop-down list of previously created categories. The problem is, the list is only populated for one of the forms on the page at a time:

[Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfdNv.png)

As you can see, only the newest form displays any data in the Category drop-down. The first two that appear on the page are now blank. The data is still there, but it is not visible. I can't figure out how to get the previous Menu Item forms to show the list of categories.

This is purely cosmetic, as the data will save correctly if I hit 'create menu'. But it does make it a pain if you want to edit the category after clicking to add a new menu item.

Here's the JQuery:

`$('form').on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
    $('.selectize').selectize();
  });`

and the form:

`<div class="field">
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.pluck(:name, :id), {}, { class: "selectize" } %>
  </div>`

I hope that was clear, not sure how to explain it in fewer words. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to check: the select-boxes show the correct contents, until you click the link to add a new menu-item, right? Because your callback will select _all_ select-boxes on the page and apply the `selectize` again, which might explain that effect? Or are the select-boxes of existing items corrupt upon loading/refreshing the page?

Comment: Partially correct. Only one select-box shows the correct content until "add new item" is clicked, after which point the new select-box that appears bears the desired dropdown content. I'm not sure why it behaves this way. FWIW I found a workaround by hiding the previous div after adding a new one to the page. It's not ideal but it appears less broken at least. The objects still maintain the correct value upon hitting submit (despite not displaying it properly) so it saves to the database correctly.

Comment: Does it work if you do not give the selectize class?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. Even with these struggles I think Selectize is the path of lesser frustration when it comes to the alternative for trying to do an "add new" field myself. Can I be of any more help? Any code snippets you'd care to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho consecutive calls of the `$('.selectize').selectize();` will "break" previously *selectized* select-boxes. So I am assuming somehow when building your view you call that try that command for each select-box, which effectively will only keep the last one in a "good" state.

So you will have to make sure to call it only once when creating your form. E.g. something like in your `menus.js.coffee` :

```
 $(document).on 'turbolinks:load', () ->
   $('.selectize').selectize()
```

And then in your cocoon callback do something like the following, to only take the newly inserted html into consideration (instead of *selectizing* *all* select-boxes again):

```
$('form').on 'cocoon:after-insert', (e, inserted_item) ->
  $(inserted_item).find('.selectize').selectize()
```